# How can make userinfo in DJS?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

This is what the console gives me:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'username')
    at Object.execute (C:\Users\USER\Documents\KromeBot\things\commands\utility\manage.js:13:33)
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\USER\Documents\KromeBot\index.js:53:17)
    at Client.emit (node:events:514:28)
    at InteractionCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\USER\Documents\KromeBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\InteractionCreate.js:97:12)
    at module.exports [as INTERACTION_CREATE] (C:\Users\USER\Documents\KromeBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\INTERACTION_CREATE.js:4:36)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\USER\Documents\KromeBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:355:31)
    at WebSocketManager.<anonymous> (C:\Users\USER\Documents\KromeBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:239:12)
    at WebSocketManager.emit (C:\Users\USER\Documents\KromeBot\node_modules\@vladfrangu\async_event_emitter\dist\index.cjs:282:31)
    at WebSocketShard.<anonymous> (C:\Users\USER\Documents\KromeBot\node_modules\@discordjs\ws\dist\index.js:1173:51)
    at WebSocketShard.emit (C:\Users\USER\Documents\KromeBot\node_modules\@vladfrangu\async_event_emitter\dist\index.cjs:282:31)
```

And this is my code:

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder, EmbedBuilder, ButtonBuilder, ButtonStyle } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName("manage")
        .setDescription("Ban, kick or view info of a user")
        .addUserOption(option =>
            option.setName("target").setDescription("Select a user").setRequired(true)
        ),
    async execute(interaction) {
        const target = interaction.options.getUser('target')
        const userinfo = new EmbedBuilder()
            .setTitle(`${target.username}`)
            .setColor(0xE12424)
            //.setThumbnail(target.displayAvatarURL())
        await interaction.reply({embeds: [userinfo]})
        //await interaction.reply(`Hi ${target}`)
    }
}
```

I was looking if there was another way, I didn't find anything. The console: TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'username')

Comment: Are you sure that you are in your command giving user what is on server and isnt bot?

Comment: /manage <@userid>

Comment: Until now I can't solve this problem, I thought I had succeeded but actually I couldn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it, it turns out that I had to redeploy the slashcommands. with deploy-commands.js. Thanks anyway.